# NHibernate CompositeUserType: How to specify Sql Types?

Tags: nhibernate, usertype, compositeusertype

Using NH 2.0, I have a custom type. It is composed of four properties,
so I implemented `ICompositeUserType`.

**I want to specify length and precision for the string and decimal properties** within the user type, to avoid specifying it with every usage in the mapping files.

But there is only a `PropertyTypes` property to implement, which returns
IType. The funny thing is, the `IUserType` has a `SqlTypes` property,
`ICompositeUserType` does not.

- Do I have to implement both interfaces?
- Do I have to implement a user type to wrap each sql-type I want to
  specify?
- Or how can I specify the Sql type for a composite user type?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it is pretty simple. I have to create the NHibernate types using the `TypeFactory`:

```
public IType[] PropertyTypes
{
  get
  {
    return new []
    {
      TypeFactory.GetDecimalType(36, 18),
      TypeFactory.GetStringType(100)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend downloading source code for this type of digging (NH 2.0).

First take a look at TypeFactory.HeuristicType method, which builds the IType instance.

```
...
else if (typeof(ICompositeUserType).IsAssignableFrom(typeClass))
{
    type = new CompositeCustomType(typeClass, parameters);
}
else if (typeof(IUserType).IsAssignableFrom(typeClass))
{
    type = new CustomType(typeClass, parameters);
}
...
```

So if your custom type implements ICompositeUserType it gets instantiated as CompositeCustomType class. This eliminates the possibility to implement both ICompositeUserType and IUserType interfaces.

Now let's take a look into CompositeCustomType

```
public override SqlType[] SqlTypes(IMapping mapping)
{
    IType[] types = userType.PropertyTypes;
    SqlType[] result = new SqlType[GetColumnSpan(mapping)];
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    {
        SqlType[] sqlTypes = types[i].SqlTypes(mapping);
        for (int k = 0; k < sqlTypes.Length; k++)
        {
            result[n++] = sqlTypes[k];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So it takes your types returned from PropertyTypes and builds the SqlType for each property. This means that providing your own user type wrappers for each property will do the trick.

Comment: You mean that I need to write a custom type for each property where I want to specify the sql type. I need to try this. I actually wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found a much simpler solution. See my own answer if you are interested in it.